# upgrading: how to remove a project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am uninstalling part of an application that involves a reference no longer used. How do I remove that project from the references folder programmatically?

In other words, I can manually click to expand the References node and delete the reference there. However, how would I do that as part of an uninstaller program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Solution::Remove(Project prj);
```

Have a look at this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.remove%28v=VS.100%29.aspx